# Using Jboss 7 and Http Components

Tags: jboss7.x, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying to use httpcomponents and jboss 7. httpcomponent's version is 4.2.2. Here is the code:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class Gnip {

@Schedule(minute="*", hour="*", persistent=false)
public void doGnip() {

    System.out.println("HTTP sending.");

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/AtmosphereTest/push?msg=100000");
    try {
        httpclient.execute(httpget);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

a timer that execute a GET every minute. Pretty simple. It compile and deploy fine, but, when the timer starts i got this:

```
    17:17:00,057 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 6) JBAS014122: Error during retrying timeout for timer: [id=08c08446-8d01-4617-902c-2becb6b26dfe timedObjectId=AtmosphereEJB.AtmosphereEJB.Gnip auto-timer?:true persistent?:true timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@5bec70c1 initialExpiration=Fri Jan 11 0
0:00:00 CET 2013 intervalDuration(in milli sec)=0 nextExpiration=Fri Jan 11 17:18:00 CET 2013 timerState=RETRY_TIMEOUT: javax.ejb.EJBException: org.apache.http.conn.s
sl.SSLInitializationException: Failure initializing default SSL context
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:166) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.TimerCMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(TimerCMTTxInterceptor.java:52) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:230) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-
7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.
1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimedObjectInvokerImpl.callTimeout(TimedObjectInvokerImpl.java:101) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.task.CalendarTimerTask.callTimeout(CalendarTimerTask.java:60) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.task.TimerTask.run(TimerTask.java:132) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.0.0.GA.jar:2.0.0.GA]
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLInitializationException: Failure initializing default SSL context
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createDefaultSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:360)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.java:175)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SchemeRegistryFactory.createDefault(SchemeRegistryFactory.java:49)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.createClientConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:306)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:466)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.createHttpContext(AbstractHttpClient.java:286)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:851)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
        at edu.pezzati.atm.ejb.Gnip.doGnip(Gnip.java:26)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_26]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFac
tory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:34) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]

        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:374) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.concurrency.ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.processInvocation(ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.java:104) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.
1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.ja
r:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.processInvocation(SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.j
ava:53) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:225)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createDefaultSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:358)
        ... 50 more
```

Do I miss some configuration to my JBoss? Looking for solution. TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I misconfigured my AS. JBoss 7.1.1 comes with a module about Httpcomponents (version 4.1.2). All I have to do is to add this:

`<global-modules>

 <module name="org.apache.httpcomponents" slot="main"/>

 </global-modules>`

to my standalone.xml. Hope someone find this helpful.